# How to refer to param in path when instantiating component in route definition? reach router v4

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

Currently, in my route.tsx i have the following defined:

```
<Route exact={true} path="/test/:id" component={Test} />
```

The Test component actually takes in a prop called id.

```
<Test id="23232"/>
```

How would you define the route to access the ":id" so it can be passed in vs. having to access the param in the Test component.

Something like

```
<Route exact={true} path="/test/:id" component={(props)=>{ <Test id={props.match.params.id} />}} />
```

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

However, you just need to adjust the syntax a bit to remove the extra set of braces:

```
<Route exact={ true } path="/test/:id" component={ (props) => <Test id={ props.match.params.id } /> } />
```

You might also want to use **render** rather than **component**:

```
<Route exact={ true } path="/test/:id" render={ (props) => <Test id={ props.match.params.id } /> } />
```

From the docs:

> When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the component attribute, you would create a new component every render. This results in the existing component unmounting and the new component mounting instead of just updating the existing component. When using an inline function for inline rendering, use the render or the children prop (below).

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component